# Is it possible to create a callback for a changed mongoid embedded document field in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Is there a way to run a callback only if an embedded document field was changed?

Currently, the following runs the callback on a normal field only if it was changed:

```
class user
  field :email, type: String
  embeds_many :connections, cascade_callbacks: true
  before_save :run_callback, :if => :email_changed?
  before_save :run_connection_callback, :if => :connections_changed?  # DOES NOT WORK
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoid won't define the method `connections_changed?` for you, but you can define it yourself by using a virtual field in `User` to keep track of when an embedded connection gets changed. That is:

```
class User

  # define reader/writer methods for @connections_changed
  attr_accessor :connections_changed

  def connections_changed?
    self.connections_changed
  end

  # the connections are no longer considered changed after the persistence action
  after_save { self.connections_changed = false }

  before_save :run_connection_callback, :if => :connections_changed?

end

class Connection
  embedded_in :user

  before_save :tell_user_about_change, :if => :changed?

  def tell_user_about_change
    user.connections_changed = true
  end
end
```

One shortcoming of this method is that `user.connections_changed` only gets set when the document is saved. The callbacks are cascaded in such a way that the `Connection` `before_save` callback gets called first and then the `User` `before save` callback, which allows the above code to work for this use case. But if you need to know whether any connections have changed before calling `save`, you'll need to find another method.

Comment: Since Mongoid 4.x (or even before) changed? and changes methods are available (see my answer below)

Answer (score 1):

**For anybody seeing this answer in 2015**

In Mongoid 4.x **model.changed?** and **model.changes** exist and behave like their ActiveRecord counterparts.